# Should I create Ubuntu software raid if I have server setup as raid?

Tags: raid

I just finished setting up my dell T310 as raid 1 with 4 disks, should I continue with Ubuntu to setting up software raid on this?

Comment: I can not tell from what you posted. If you have hardware raid, do not use software raid, one or the other . People generally prefer software raid (mdam) because the hardware drivers for linux can be missing or poorly documented. See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Raid

Comment: i have hardware raid enabled and ended up partitioning the raid of 4 drives using raid 1 now equals 1 drive into an 8gb and 240gb.

Comment: As long as Ubuntu recognized the hardware raid (ie Ubuntu sees the hardware raid as 1 hard driver) you are good to go. The only "limitation" you might have is if one of the drives fails you need to use the tool provided by your vendor. I had to use megaraid. See https://wiki.debian.org/LinuxRaidForAdmins

Comment: Looks like this - https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Hardware_Raid_Setup_using_MegaCli